# Is UTP of any benefit for RS-232?

Tags: rs232, wiring

I have an RFID module I want to mount in the driver's window of a car. It connects to a box that will probably be in the footwell. It uses 5v RS-232. Given that RS-232 isn't balanced, is there any advantage in using UTP cable to connect the two? If so, what would the wiring look like? At a minimum, I'd need power, ground, and a simplex data line, but if I could control a couple of LEDs over that too, that'd be great (presumably they could share a pair, as they're constant voltages).

If there's no advantage, is there a disadvantage to doing so? It's just for a prototype, and I happen to have plenty of Cat5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no advantage, but there's little harm. Perhaps by using UTP (the *U* meaning *Unshielded*), you will lose some of the RFI protection offered by the shield. I seriously doubt you will miss it, though. I bet most implementations don't take any special precautions to keep the noise currents on the shield away from the receiving circuitry anyway. Typical RS-232 speeds are low enough and noise margins high enough that it doesn't make a big difference.

You won't get any advantage because the impedances of the ground and signal lines in RS-232 are not equal. Thus, induced noise will result in unequal voltages on each conductor, and so the noise won't be entirely common-mode, and thus won't be entirely rejected by the receiver.

If you did want a serial protocol designed to work (and take advantage of) balanced lines, consider [RS-485](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485).

Comment: [RS-422](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-422) is more of a direct replacement, being full duplex.

Comment: @Marko Indeed, that's better. I was only 63 off :)

Comment: RS485 can be full duplex also, right?

Comment: Nope, RS-485 only has one (bi-directional) pair. It's neat feature is that it can be half duplex between a whole network of devices, whereas 422 can only have a single master (it can have multiple slaves, though, but they then have to take turns sharing the tx-to-master pair)

Comment: In this case, only simplex is required anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Although RS-232 doesn't use differential signaling, so that the cables don't use twisted differential pairs, it is nevertheless advantageous to twist the conductors together in order to cancel EMI. The conductors in serial cable are twisted together.

Conductors don't have to be twisted in pairs. Suppose that the cable contains a RX, TX and common ground line: an odd number. The three can simply be twisted, like a screw with three threads, or braided like a ponytail.  The cable as a whole then has no net loop area for picking up EMI.

Interference doesn't read schematics: it just attacks a loop area, not caring whether that is a differential pair, or a single-ended signal-ground combo.

There is no special advantage of the Cat5 cable over serial cable for RS-232, but it should do the job and you can get long runs of it for low cost due to its popularity.

Comment: I wouldn't twist RX and TX. It only increases crosstalk.